# Javascript value of a single radio button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that can have a varible number of radio buttons. From one to sixteen. I have a switch statement where I want various actions to happen if the user presses a certian button. If they press the number one on the numberic keypad, I want the first radio button to be selected and the form to be submitted.

```
case 97:
                            document.form_name.radio[0].checked=true;
                            document.form_name.submit();
                            break;
```

This works when there is more than one radio button in the form but when there is only one, it doesn't work.
I can find out before I execute to code how many radio buttons are in the form. What code to I need to use the check the radio button, if it is the only one?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `querySelector` since it only selects the FIRST anyway. You can also use `querySelectorAll` and the position in the array to select any other radios also.

```js
document.querySelector("input[name='drop_items']").checked=true;
//document.querySelectorAll("input[name='drop_items']")[1].checked=true;
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="drop_items" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="drop_items" value="12">
```

Comment: Do you know why it doesn't work for the first one? Would your code work if there was more than one item, or woule I have to use your code only when there is one item?

Comment: @RichardYoung, I'm not exactly sure why yours doesn't work. But mine will work as long as you have at least 1, with no max.

Comment: The Consle when you select the item says radio[0] is unspecified but only when there is one item.

Comment: @RichardYoung, I suspect the problem is because radio buttons are meant to have at least two (ie ON/OFF). Whereas checkboxes can be 1 to infinity. So radio buttons are technically part of an array

Comment: That's what I thought. Can't an array have just one value that is array[0] though?

Comment: But is the querySelector the only way to check it?

Comment: Thanks imvain2. You comment helped me. I found if there was only one radio button, I didn't need to [0] at the end.